# Detect if php is called from a src?

Tags: php

So here's a question. Can a `php` script detect how it is being called? For example if it is called through `<img>` it will return an image, or if it is being called through `<video>` it will return video, or if it is called through `<audio>` it will return audio, or if it is called directly by typing in `http://www.example.com/callme.php` it will return some text.

The content from this `callme.php` would be provided through the following method:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; "
.sprintf('filename="%s"; ', rawurlencode($_REQUEST['F']))
.sprintf("filename*=utf-8''%s", rawurlencode($_REQUEST['F'])));
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
flush(); // this doesn't really matter.

$fp = fopen($file, "r") or die("DEAD");
while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536);
    flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Why do you need such a requirement? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Progman Was hoping to deny people certain access depending on how the resource was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible, at least not without some additional parameters in the URL.

Consider the following HTML

```
<img src="/callme.php?target=img" />
```

With the following PHP:

```
if ($_GET('target') == 'img') { ... }
```

Comment: Darn... That would mean that anyone could manually type in `callme.php?target=img` and get the image rather than the text.

Comment: If the reason you want to do this is security related then you are going about things the complete wrong way...